# Elliptic Deformations of Multiplication

Tags: abstract-algebra, complex-analysis, complex-numbers

Consider the squared absolute value function on complex numbers $a+bi \rightarrow a^2+b^2$.

It's easy to verify that the squared absolute value is a homomorphism over multiplication. That is
$$ |(a+bi)(c+di)|^2 =  (ac - bd) + (ad+bc)i = (ac-bd)^2 + (ad+bc)^2 = (ac)^2-2acbd+(bd)^2 + (ad)^2 + 2abcd + (bc)^2 = (ac)^2+(bd)^2+(ad)^2+(bc)^2= (a^2+b^2)(c^2+d^2)= |(a+bi)|^2|(c+di)|^2$$

If we define an elliptic absolute value as the map given a choice of $(u,v)$ and a complex number $a+bi \rightarrow \frac{a^2}{u^2} + \frac{b^2}{v^2}$ we can easily see that unless we have $u=v=1$ this function almost surely doesn't respect multiplication. (We can try some difference choices of $u,v$ to see this for ourselves).

So now we get to a very subjective question, what if we insist there ought to be an operation like multiplication, what we shall call a $(u,v)$-deformation of multiplication, which has the property that the $(u,v)$-elliptic absolute value respects this operation, and this operation is in some sense as "natural" as possible. We could probably say that the foci of the ellipse generated by $(u,v)$ would replace the function of 0 w.r.t this multiplication.

What would be some candidates for such a multiplication?

Some Preliminary thoughts:

If we have a complex function $\Psi$ that maps the unit circle to an ellipse centered at 0. Then we can define multiplication on the ellipse by taking two points $\rho_1, \rho_2$ and computing $\Psi(\Psi^{-1}(\rho_1)\Psi^{-1}(\rho_2))$.

This new multiplication operation at the least would "respect" our elliptic squared absolute values for the unit ellipse of a particular $(u,v)$ class.

It's meaningful then to ask, given a $(u,v)$ pair what is the space of meromorphic functions that map complex circles of radius $r$ to the ellipse $x^2/u^2 + y^2/v^2 = r^2$.

These would create can candidates for making an elliptical multiplication.

Comment: **squared** absolute value function

Comment: Of course we can take the ordinary complex multiplication and absolute value, and just replace $\{1,i\}$ by a different basis (or apply a linear transformation), so that the circles look like ellipses, and the absolute value has the form you give with respect to the new coordinates. But that's not very interesting.

Comment: ...Though it is related to the fact that, up to isomorphism, there are only three unital algebras on $\mathbb R^2$ (not assumed to be commutative or associative, but 
those follow anyway): the complex numbers with $i^2=-1$, the perplex numbers with $i^2=+1$, and the dual numbers with $i^2=0$. These three (classes of) algebras are associated with ellipses, hyperbolas, and pairs of parallel lines, respectively. In fact for any such algebra there's a natural "squared absolute value", the determinant of the multiplication map, which is constant along such conics.

Comment: Do you want the "multiplication" to distribute over addition?

Comment: Well no it would have to distribute over a deformed addition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By your assumptions,

$$\Psi(re^{i\theta})=r\Psi(e^{i\theta})=r\big(u\cos\psi(\theta)+iv\sin\psi(\theta)\big)$$

for some real function $\psi$.

The [Cauchy-Riemann equations in polar coordinates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Riemann_equations#Other_representations) are

$$ir\frac{\partial\Psi}{\partial r}=\frac{\partial\Psi}{\partial\theta};$$

that is,

$$ir(u\cos\psi+iv\sin\psi)=r(-u\sin\psi+iv\cos\psi)\psi'.$$

Cancelling $r$ and separating into real and imaginary parts,

$$-v\sin\psi=-u\sin\psi\,\psi',\quad u\cos\psi=v\cos\psi\,\psi'.$$

Since $\Psi$ is invertible, $\psi$ is not constantly a multiple of $\pi/2$, so we can cancel $\cos\psi$ and $\sin\psi$:

$$v=u\psi',\quad u=v\psi'$$

$$\psi'=\frac vu=\frac uv$$

$$u=\pm v$$

$$\psi=\pm\theta+C$$

$$\Psi(re^{i\theta})=ru\,e^{\pm i\psi}=re^{i\theta}\cdot ue^{\pm iC}$$

Thus $\Psi$ must be multiplication by a constant, and the ellipse must be a circle.

Comment: I’m digesting this right now, will be back with my thoughts

Comment: It looks then to find something cool question needs to be re-asked but my assumptions on $\Psi$ relaxed, I guess this puts the nail into the coffin of what I proposed here.

Answer (score 1):

My two cents comment: I find the representation of your question a bit tautological. Here is why.

**My understanding of your question**

Let $\tau : \mathbb{C} \rightarrow \mathbb{R_+}$ denote our ellipstic squared absolute value, that is:
$$\tau(a+ib)= \dfrac{a^2}{u^2}+\dfrac{b^2}{v^2}$$
So if I understand correctly, you want to find a binary operation $*$ from $\mathbb{C} \times \mathbb{C}$ to $\mathbb{C}$ such that:

- $(\mathbb{C}, *)$ is a semigroup
- $\tau( a*b) = \tau(a)\tau(b)$

**My main comment**
Our quest for such multiplication for $\tau$ is equivalent to a question for a multiplication that preserves the structure of the usual absolute value.

**Explanation**

You see, for any bijective function $\phi: \mathbb{C} \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$
I can define another binary operation $\times$ such that:
$$\phi(a)\times \phi(b) = \phi( a*b)$$
(Thank to the bijectivity of $\phi$)
Furthermore, we can see that $(\mathbb{C},\times)$ is a semigroup.
Indeed, for any complex numbers $x,y,z$, there are three complex numbers $a,b,c$ such that: $$\phi(a)=x, \phi(b)=y , \phi(c)=z$$
and therefore,
$$(x \times y ) \times z = ( \phi(a) \times \phi(b) ) \times  \phi(c) = \phi( a*b) \times \phi(c) = \phi ( (a*b)*c)$$
and  likewise,
$$x \times( y  \times z )=  \phi(a) \times (\phi(b)  \times  \phi(c) )= \phi( a) \times \phi(b*c) = \phi ( a*(b*c))$$
as $*$ is associative, $\times$ also is.

Besides, also by definition of $\phi$
$$ \tilde{\tau}( a \times b) =\tilde{\tau}( a ) \tilde{\tau}( b ) $$
where $\tilde{\tau} =\tau\circ \phi^{-1} $

Then, by choosing $\phi$ to be an appropriate deformation function in $\mathbb{C}$, say $\phi(a+ib)= a/u+ib/v$ ,  we can have
$$\tilde{tau}( a+ib)= a^2+b^2$$

**In short**
We are just finding something for the usual absolute value.

Comment: Thank you for this, everything stated here is correct but considering $\phi(a+ib) = a/u + ib/v$ is not so interesting to me since its a function that can't be expressed as a function of $a+ib$ alone using any sequence/series of known meromorphic functions [or if it can that would be cool to see]. What I didn't make explicit was that the new multiplication lets call it $(x,y) \rightarrow H(x,y)$ should be analytic least for some open set of $(x,y) \in \mathbb{C}^2$. I.E expressible as a a power series in its arguments $(x,y)$.

Comment: I also hope to see such multiplication. However, what I meant by this post is that the elliptic nature of this question is not that much of interest because any multiplication we can find (for $(u,v)$ -elliptic absolute values) corresponds one-one to a multiplication for the usual absolute value in $\mathbb{C}$